# Resetting time.clock() in Python

Tags: python

```
import time

start = time.clock()
while True:
  elapsed = (time.clock() - start)
  if elapsed > 10:
    print("MOTION")
    elapsed = 0
```

I start a timer, calculate elapsed time, and if 10 seconds have passed, I display "MOTION" and then reset elapsed to 0 so "MOTION" only displays every 10 seconds.  For some reason, it doesn't work: MOTION does initially get displayed after 10 seconds, but after that, it keeps getting displayed on every iteration.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: instead of setting elapsed as 0, you need to set `start = time.clock()`

Comment: **DeprecationWarning:** **`time.clock`** has been deprecated in Python 3.3 and will be removed from Python 3.8: use **`time.perf_counter`** or **`time.process_time`** instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options; your code doesn't work because you are trying to reset the clock but instead you reset `elapsed`, which does nothing.

**Using modulo division.**

```
start = time.clock()
while True:
  elapsed = (time.clock() - start)
  if int(elapsed) % 10:
    print("MOTION")
```

**Resetting the clock.**

```
start = time.clock()
while True:
  elapsed = (time.clock() - start)
  if elapsed >= 10:
    print("MOTION")
    start = time.clock()
```

Answer (score 1):

You neglected to reset your reference time: change the basis, not the interval.  On each iteration, you reset `elapsed` to 0, but then immediately go back to the original start time.  Change the last line of you loop:

```
start = time.clock()
while True:
  elapsed = (time.clock() - start)
  if elapsed > 10:
    print("MOTION")
    start = time.clock()
```